# Formatting float to round to two decimals in a print function

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I have the following code:

```
print ("Cost: %f per %s" % (mrate[choice], munit[choice]))
```

Output:

```
Cost: 25.770000 per 10gm tube
```

How can I get it to round to two decimals while printing, so that I get 25.77 in the output?

Comment: `print ("Cost: %.2f per %s" % (mrate[choice], munit[choice]))`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print ("Cost: %f" % 25.77)
Cost: 25.770000
>>> print ("Cost: %.2f" % 25.77)
Cost: 25.77
```

Unsure where to find it exactly in PyDoc, but at least the same width-precision rules can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `%.2f` you will get 2 decimal places for you float like:

#### Test Code:

```
value = 25.7700000001
print("%f %.2f" % (value, value))
```

#### Results:

```
25.770000 25.77
```

Answer (score 1):

use round function to restrict decimal places.

print ("Cost: %.2f per %s" % (round(mrate[choice],2), munit[choice]))

Or replace "%f" with "%.2f"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use format specifications in your `print` function like this:

```
value = 25.7700000001
print("%.2f" % (value))
```